# How to dump nested list using SnakeYAML

Tags: scala, yaml

I'm parsing this yaml file

```
View:
  from : 01.01.2007
  to : 04.01.2007
  driver : sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

using SnakeYAML in Scala like this:

```
val stream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/config_view.yml")
var configMap: Map[String, Any] = new Yaml().load(stream).asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, Any]].asScala
var view = configMap("View").asInstanceOf[java.util.LinkedHashMap[String, String]].asScala

view = view + ("from" -> "neu") // some test modifying
```

and I dump it like this:

```
val fileWriter = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\test.yml")
new Yaml().dump(Map[String, Any]("View" -> view.asJava).asJava, fileWriter)
```

which saves the new yaml file like this:

```
View: {driver: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver, from: neu, to: 04.01.2007}
```

But I want it to save it like this:

```
View:
  driver: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
  from: neu
  to: 04.01.2007
```

How can I tell SnakeYAML to save it in the desired format you see above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about manually handling the indentation and `key: value` formatting:

```
view.map{ case (k,v) => s"\t$k: $v\n" }
```

In the case of nested maps you will want a method that

- accepts the current "level" of nesting. Place the `level` tabs in front of the output to give the proper output nesting
- checks each of the entries. If it were another collection type then it needs to recursively invoke itself - which will increase the indention level

Comment: Yeah thanks for the advice. I wrote a function like you said and dumped the map using the standard FileWriter instead of using Yaml::dump since that function doesn't escape tabs and newlines.

Answer (score 7):

By default SnakeYAML uses the `DumperOptions.FlowStyle.FLOW` but it can be changed to the `DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK` that will dump the data with the desired format.

An example in Kotlin:

```
val options = DumperOptions()
options.indent = 2
options.defaultFlowStyle = DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK
Yaml(options).dump(yourObject)
```